# Having problems launching Python3 command. Module 'lib' has no attribute 'core'

Tags: python-3.x

This is the log I get when launching a pentesting tool:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "web-brutator.py", line 7, in <module>
    from lib.core.ArgumentsParser import ArgumentsParser
  File "/home/pc/web-brutator/lib/core/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .ArgumentsParser import *
  File "/home/pc/web-brutator/lib/core/ArgumentsParser.py", line 9, in <module>
    import lib.core.Globals as Globals
AttributeError: module 'lib' has no attribute 'core'
```

The `ArgumentsParser.py`, line 9:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import argparse
import os
import re

from lib.core.Config import *
from lib.core.Utils import Utils, LineWrapRawTextHelpFormatter
import lib.core.Globals as Globals

class ArgumentsParser:
```

```
python3 --version
Python 3.6.9
```

Do I need to downgrade any Python module or reinstall any different version? It seems to me some kind of incompatibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is solved using python3.8
I noticed after checking the python version that I have 3.6 in update-alternatives

Comment: Please accept this answer by clicking the green tick under the score to help future users find this answer more easily.